# Using a case column within another case in select clause

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a select clause with a `case` statement  and I need to create another `case` statement comparing the column created by the previous `case` statement. Something like this:

```
select client
    ,discount
    ,(case when sales_avg>10000 then 30 
        when sales_avg>5000 then 20 
        else 0 end) discount_rule
    ,(case when discount < discount_rule then 1 else 0 end) status 
from sales;
```

I get a message that `discount_rule is unknown`. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You can use a subquery or CTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a subquery that returns the column `discount_rule`:

```
select t.client, t.discount, t.discount_rule,
  case 
    when discount < discount_rule then 1 
    else 0 
  end status
from (
  select client, discount,
    case 
      when sales_avg > 10000 then 30 
      when sales_avg > 5000 then 20 
      else 0 
    end discount_rule
  from sales
) t
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *Common Table Expression* (CTE) and reference a CTE within a CTE as:

```
with CTE_discount_rule as
(
       select client,
              discount,
       (case when sales_avg>10000 then 30
             when sales_avg>5000 then 20 
             else 0 end) as discount_rule
       from sales
),
CTE_Final_Status as
(
  select client,
         discount,
         discount_rule,
         (case when discount < discount_rule then 1 else 0 end) as status 
  from CTE_discount_rule

)
select * from CTE_Final_Status;
```

Comment: Your answer used Microsoft SQL Server syntax, I have replaced it with the equivalent Firebird syntax.